# Find sphere equation

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres, solid-geometry

How to find **sphere equation** with **center in plane** $\pi =\{x-5y+z-2=0\}$ and **tangent to plane** $\alpha =\{ 2x+3y-4z-1=0 \}$ at $M(1,1,1)$

Where I've stopped:

Knowing the sphere equation is: $$(X-a)^2 + (Y-b)^2 + (Z-c)^2 = r^2$$
Center of sphere is $C(a,b,c)$ and can be found in plane $\pi$

$r^2$ is radius and can be found doing distance from center of sphere to tangent point M ( $d(C,M)$ )
My problem is center point, how can I find this? My first thought was something using plane $\pi$ but then plane $\alpha$ was given in question and never used.

Comment: The answer is not nice.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Radius and tangent are perpendicular. Where does the perpendicular to $\alpha$ at $M$ hit $\pi$?

**A different way:** Parametrize the plane $\pi$, then find for which value of the parameters the vector $\vec{MP}$ (with $P\in\pi$) is orthogonal to $\alpha$.

Comment: In projection of M on $\alpha$  $M'$  ?

Comment: @MihaiPreda Sorry, what? I suggest that you find the line that is orthogonal to $\alpha$ at point $M$ and then where this line hits $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$$MC: (1,1,1)+t(2,3,-4).$$
Let $C(1+2t,1+3t,1-4t).$

Thus,
$$1+2t-5(1+3t)+1-4t-2=0,$$ which gives $t=-\frac{5}{17},$
$$C\left(\frac{7}{17},\frac{2}{17},\frac{37}{17}\right),$$
$$MC=\sqrt{\frac{725}{289}}$$ and the answer is
$$\left(x-\frac{7}{17}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{2}{17}\right)^2+\left(z-\frac{37}{17}\right)^2=\frac{725}{289}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The center of the sphere is the intersection of the plane $\pi $ with the line passing through $M$ and perpendicular to $\alpha$

The equation of the line passing through M and perpendicular to $\alpha$ is $$x=1+2t, y=1+3t, z=1-4t$$

The point of intersection with $\pi $ is $$ C(7/{17},2/{17},37/{17})$$which is the center of the sphere.

The radius is simply $CM$ the distance between $C$ and $M$.